# what does ":" mean or do in Dart?

Tags: class, flutter, dart, operators, subclass

I have been trying to get an clear explanation for what : means in dart.

As far as I can tell it seems so be some kind of operator , but I can't get a clear cut explanation of what exactly it does.

I understand that it gets used to so assign stuff to other stuff , but I am unsure of the specifics.

I have tried googling it , no luck.

I have tried searching through the dart documentation.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators

I know that it gets used as part of conditional expressions like here:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions

Here are examples of how it gets used:

Example 1 :

```
class someBloc extends Bloc<someEvent, someState> {
    someBloc() : super(someState.initial());
}
```

Example 2 :

```
class someClass {
  final String requestType;
  final String name; 
   
  factory someClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return SomeClass(
            requestType: json['Type'],
            name: json['Name']);
      }
}
```

Comment: When searching for "colon" in the dart documentation I found this : https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list , but this only explains Example 1 , and from the below answers I managed to get the following https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters. Could the answer to the question be that the meaning of ":" is conditional based on where it is getting used ?

Answer (score 0):

In examples 1 & 2:

The `:` is used to set a named parameter. For example, let's say I want to create a `Card` widget. The `card` widget optionally takes a **named** parameter called `elevation`. Therefore, I can do this:

```
Card(
  elevation: 4.0,
)
```

---

Another way `:` is used is for writing quick conditional expressions.

```
final String isMyListEmpty = myList.isEmpty ? 'Yes, the list is empty' : 'No, the list is not empty';
```

In this example, our condition is `myList.isEmpty`. If this condition is true, the first expression after `?` is returned. Else, if the condition is false, the expression after the `:` is returned.

(Edited to correct `??` usage to `?`)

Comment: I don't quite understand, what named parameter is being set in example 1 ?

Comment: @PieterScholtz [elevation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card/elevation.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's just an assignment operator. You assign a value to a widget property. For example, Container widget has many properties, like color or height:

```
  Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    color: Colors.amber[600],
    width: 48.0,
    height: 48.0,
  ),
```

Comment: While it has this effect, it is not an assignment operator and it does not assign to properties. The example you have is about setting named parameters. You probably mixed that up because the properties are commonly also named parameters of the constructor. But that is a convention, other people could program their widgets differently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but just saw this didn't have an accepted answer because they are incomplete.  So let's look at the examples from the original question.

## Example 1:

```dart
class someBloc extends Bloc<someEvent, someState> {
    someBloc() : super(someState.initial());
}
```

This was the strangest for me to adjust to when first learning dart.  This `:` is either a [redirecting constructor](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#redirecting-constructors) or starts an initializer list (which may also call a super constructor) for the constructor `someBloc()` (which would typically be PascalCase, but I'm matching the given example).  Specifically, this is a [Super-initializer](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#super-parameters). In the example, it is passing the `someState.initial()` as the parameter to the super constructor on the Bloc class because SomeBloc extends Bloc.  This is essentially the same practice as making sure to call the super constructor as the first line of the constructor in a sub class in other OOP languages.

This can be a helpful way to initialize other final class member variables (not shown in the example) here that are not set through passed in parameters.

## Example 2:

There may be a typo in this example.  As it stands, there would need to be another constructor with [named parameters](https://dart.dev/language/functions#named-parameters). Something like:

```dart
someClass({required this.requestType, required this.name});
```

If this were the case, then the `:` is setting the value of the named parameter.  This means that the parameters can be set in either order because the `name:` and `requestType:` will pick the correct parameter since those were declared in the constructor with curly braces around them`{}`.

```dart
class someClass {
  final String requestType;
  final String name; 
   
  factory someClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return someClass(
            requestType: json['Type'],
            name: json['Name']);
      }
}
```

## Example 3:

The [Ternary Conditional Operator](https://dart.dev/language/operators) `? and :`
You'll find this short hand in many programming languages

```dart
var myValue = someBoolean ? ifTrue : ifFalse;

// equivalent to
var myValue;
if(someBoolean){
  myValue = ifTrue;
} else {
  myValue = ifFalse;
}
```